# How to change the default simulator in xcode open developer tool

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I've added the ios 15.5 simulator  Xcode 14.3, which comes with built-in ios 16.4. When I select xcode->Open Developer Tool->simulator, the iPhone 14 Pro Max launches. (16.4) Is there a way to alter the default setting to (iPhone 13 pro 15.5)

Answer (score 0):

The Simulator app has a setting to restart the last simulators that were used when last quit.

Run the Simulator app and go to Settings and then in the Simulator Lifetime section, enable the "When Simulator starts boot the most recently used simulator".

With that option enabled, if you have an iPhone 13 Pro w/ iOS 15.5 simulator running and you quit the Simulator app, then the next time you start the Simulator app, the same iPhone 13 Pro w/ iOS 15.5 simulator will be started again automatically.